# How to wrap a structure (with macros maybe) to store its field in map

Tags: c++

Is there a way to wrap a structure (with some kind of macros) to have a possibility to proceed some work with fields name and values.
Assume the structure:

```
struct Config {
 double param_1 = 1.0;
 double param_2 = 2.0;
 double param_3 = 3.0;
}
```

I would like to write some Wrapper around this structure to get smth like this after preprocessing:

```
struct Wrapped_Config {
   struct Config {
     double param_1;
     double param_2;
     double param_3;
   }
  std::map<string, double> val = {{"param_1", 1.0}, {"param_2", 2.0}, {"param_3", 3.0}}
  Config get_copy { return Config{val["param_1"], val["param_2"], val["param_3"]};}
}
```

Comment: Since you don't show any actual use for the field-name:value map, it's really hard to tell what this would achieve. Why do you want `WrappedConfig::get_copy()` to do something different than `return {};`, since the values can be default-initialized anyway?

Comment: Yes, there is a certain need to have this map. The main question is not why I do need that, but whether it is possible.

Comment: My point is that you haven't provided enough information about what the map is for, to judge what solutions might be suitable. There is no direct way to do exactly what you ask; you could probably engineer something with `BOOST_PP`, but it'll be horrible. You could use reflection, but it isn't yet standardized. Otherwise, whatever you do will depend on what exactly you need from it, which you've refused to clarify.